# Saving the plots in igraph as igraph object or gml format

Tags: r

I have the following code to detect the communities from a correlation matrix using the walktrap community algorithm. Once the communities were detected , I plotted them.

```
 G <- graph.adjacency(th, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
 G <- delete.vertices(G, V(G)[ degree(G)==0 ])
 G1<-walktrap.community(G)
 par(mai=c(0.4,0.01,0.01,0.4)) 
 b<-plot(G1,G,vertex.size=15,vertex.label.color= "black",vertex.label.cex=0.45,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

What I would like to do is to have an interactive version of the plot which shows the different communities or save them in a  format that could be imported into cytoscape.I tried the following:

```
 tkplot(G1,G,vertex.size=15,vertex.label.color= "black",vertex.label.cex=0.45,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

But I get the following error:

```
   Error in tkplot(G1, G, vertex.size = 15, vertex.label.color = "black",  :
```

Not a graph object

I tried to convert the plot into the gml format to import into cytoscape but failed.

Answer (score 1):

`G1` is not a graph here, but a hierarchical community structure. `tkplot()` can plot graphs, but not community structures. If you want a plot that shows the communities at the highest modularity level, encoded using vertex colors, then you can do something like:

```
mycolors <- heat.colots(length(G1))
tkplot(G, vertex.color=mycolors[membership(G1)])
```